# How do i create my own DSL on dotnet core, are there frameworks?

Tags: c#, dsl

Sorry if my title is way off, but i have no clue where to start on this.

I came up with a little format that allow me to write some small steps in a json file. People knowing azure resource templates, its very much inspired by this.

`{
  "steps": [
    {
      "command": "mpc-info -i [laz input directory] -c [number processes]",
      "outputs": {
        "AABB": "[split(regex(stdout,\"\\('AABB: ', (.*?)\\)\",$1))]"
      }
    }
  ]
}`

Where to i start if i want to write my own parser for those "[]" strings in the document?

Goal being that its easy for me to add new functions / variables that can be used to write expressions. I would like to define all this in c# code running on dotnet core netstandard 2.0.

So in the specifc instance above, a host program will run the command and produce some output on stdout. I now need my code to parse the output string 
`[split(regex(stdout,\"\\('AABB: ', (.*?)\\)\",$1))]` and translate that into code that will run a Regex match on the variable stdout and return the first capture group as a argument to a split function that will create an array object of the items and replacing at the end the string in the JToken object.

Any pointers on what to read up or sample code that could get it started.

My naiv approch would just be write some studid code that do some search and replace and solve this small example, but what if i want to evolve my small framework with more functions ect.

Where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of help from twitter friends i managed to solve the problem using Sprache.

stdout.txt

```
Completed 100.00%!()
('AABB: ', 480000, 6150000, -1580, 530000, 6200000, 755)
('#Points:', 20517377941)
('Average density [pts / m2]:', 8.2069511764)
('Suggested number of tiles: ', 16.0)
('Suggested Potree-OctTree CAABB: ', 480000, 6150000, -1580, 530000, 6200000, 48420)
('Suggested Potree-OctTree spacing: ', 205.0)
('Suggested Potree-OctTree number of levels: ', 11)
Suggested potreeconverter command:
$(which PotreeConverter) -o <potree output directory> -l 11 -s 205 --CAABB "480000 6150000 -1580 530000 6200000 48420" --output-format LAZ -i <laz input directory>
Finished in 7.63 seconds
```

and a unit test that shows how it work

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{

    var parser = new ExpressionParser();
    parser.Functions["add"] = (arguments) => 
        arguments.Aggregate(0.0, (acc, argument) => acc + argument.ToObject<double>());

    parser.Functions["split"] = (arguments) => JArray.FromObject(arguments.Single().ToString().Split(","));
    parser.Functions["regex"] = RegexFunc;

    Assert.AreEqual(4.0, parser.Evaluate("[add(2,2)]"));
    Assert.AreEqual(7.0, parser.Evaluate("[add(2,2,3)]"));
    Assert.AreEqual(3.0, parser.Evaluate("[add(2,2,-1)]"));
    Assert.AreEqual(4.0, parser.Evaluate("[add(2,2,0,0)]"));

    var stdout = File.ReadAllText("stdout.txt");

    var test = parser.Evaluate("[split(regex(\"testfoo\",\"test(.*)\",\"$1\"))]");

    Assert.AreEqual("[\"foo\"]",test.ToString( Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None));


    parser.Functions["stdout"] = (arguments) => stdout;
    parser.Functions["numbers"] = (arguments) => new JArray(arguments.SelectMany(c => c).Select(c => double.Parse(c.ToString())));

    var AABB = parser.Evaluate("[numbers(split(regex(stdout(2),\"\\('AABB: ', (.*?)\\)\",\"$1\")))]");

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 480000, 6150000, -1580, 530000, 6200000, 755 }, AABB.ToObject<int[]>());
}
```

and the actual implementation

```
public class ConstantEvaluator : IJTokenEvaluator
{
    private string k;

    public ConstantEvaluator(string k)
    {
        this.k = k;
    }

    public JToken Evaluate()
    {
        return JToken.Parse(k);
    }
}
public class DecimalConstantEvaluator : IJTokenEvaluator
{
    private decimal @decimal;

    public DecimalConstantEvaluator(decimal @decimal)
    {
        this.@decimal = @decimal;
    }

    public JToken Evaluate()
    {
        return JToken.FromObject(@decimal);
    }
}
public class StringConstantEvaluator : IJTokenEvaluator
{
    private string text;

    public StringConstantEvaluator(string text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public JToken Evaluate()
    {
        return text;
    }
}
public interface IJTokenEvaluator
{
    JToken Evaluate();
}
public class FunctionEvaluator : IJTokenEvaluator
{
    private string name;
    private IJTokenEvaluator[] parameters;
    private ExpressionParser evaluator;
    public FunctionEvaluator(ExpressionParser evaluator, string name, IJTokenEvaluator[] parameters)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.parameters = parameters;
        this.evaluator = evaluator;
    }

    public JToken Evaluate()
    {
        return evaluator.Evaluate(name, parameters.Select(p => p.Evaluate()).ToArray());
    }


}

public class ExpressionParser
{
    public readonly Parser<IJTokenEvaluator> Function;
    public readonly Parser<IJTokenEvaluator> Constant;

    private static readonly Parser<char> DoubleQuote = Parse.Char('"');
    private static readonly Parser<char> Backslash = Parse.Char('\\');

    private static readonly Parser<char> QdText =
        Parse.AnyChar.Except(DoubleQuote);
    private static readonly Parser<char> QuotedPair =
        from _ in Backslash
        from c in Parse.AnyChar
        select c;

    private static readonly Parser<StringConstantEvaluator> QuotedString =
        from open in DoubleQuote
        from text in QdText.Many().Text()
        from close in DoubleQuote
        select new StringConstantEvaluator(text);

    public Dictionary<string, Func<JToken[], JToken>> Functions { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, Func<JToken[], JToken>>();

    private readonly Parser<IJTokenEvaluator> Number = from op in Parse.Optional(Parse.Char('-').Token())
                                                       from num in Parse.Decimal
                                                       from trailingSpaces in Parse.Char(' ').Many()
                                                       select new DecimalConstantEvaluator(decimal.Parse(num) * (op.IsDefined ? -1 : 1));
    public ExpressionParser()
    {
        Function = from name in Parse.Letter.AtLeastOnce().Text()
                   from lparen in Parse.Char('(')
                   from expr in Parse.Ref(() => Function.Or(Number).Or(QuotedString).Or(Constant)).DelimitedBy(Parse.Char(',').Token())
                   from rparen in Parse.Char(')')
                   select CallFunction(name, expr.ToArray());

        Constant = Parse.LetterOrDigit.AtLeastOnce().Text().Select(k => new ConstantEvaluator(k));
    }

    public JToken Evaluate(string name, params JToken[] arguments)
    {
        return Functions[name](arguments);

    }

    IJTokenEvaluator CallFunction(string name, IJTokenEvaluator[] parameters)
    {
        return new FunctionEvaluator(this, name, parameters);
    }

    public JToken Evaluate(string str)
    {
        var stringParser = //Apparently the name 'string' was taken...
             from first in Parse.Char('[')
             from text in this.Function
             from last in Parse.Char(']')
             select text;



        var func = stringParser.Parse(str);

        return func.Evaluate();
    }



}
```

Comment: @poul-k-sørensen Thank you for adding a response to your own question, this is super helpful

Comment: Was a fun project. Let me know if this would be usefull as a nuget with some of the abtraction done for you